# Print Image prints gray image on preview page

Tags: html, printing

I am trying to print a colored image but it is showing gray image in preview page

Please help

Answer (score 0):

On your print preview you have your color set to black an white. Change it to colored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using black and white printer so you are geting black and white print priview. If i'm wrong go to printer preference seting.